# Does "gone astray" mean the same as losing the way?

Tags: meaning, understanding

If I walk along a hiking path and I lose my way somehow, can I say that I am gone astray?

Comment: In principle you *could* say *I **have** gone astray* (not *... **am** gone astray*, which sounds somewhat medieval), but it wouldn't be very common. Bear in mind that the "core" sense of ***stray*** is *move away **aimlessly** [from a group, or from the right course or place]*. So sheep stray because they wander away (from the group/herd) and become "lost" *from the shepherd's point of view*. But idiomatically when applied to a *person,* we usually mean (figurative) *strayed **from the path of righteousness***. So just stick to *I am lost* (I don't know where I am, or how to get somewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes *'astray'* has that meaning but in *hiking context* it is better if you say something like:

> (I think) I am off course

or

> (I think) I am off path

or

> I believe I have lost my bearings

***Lost one's bearings:*** [(Oxford Dictionary)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/bearing?q=bearings#bearing__7)

> <sup>*6.1*</sup> **(one's bearings)** Awareness of one’s position relative to one’s surroundings:
>
> ***example***: Adam couldn't get his bearings from his position on the ground.

Answer (score 4):

It seems to me that while having its roots in the expression of "*becoming stray*" (becoming one without a definite direction in one's going), to "**go astray**" has started to lose its direct, or perhaps original, meaning and is now used mostly figuratively, I think.  In my encounters with English (both through books, media, and everyday conversations) I cannot recall any recent example of using "go astray" in a literal sense, as to "lose one's path while hiking".

So, yes, you *can* say "I have/am gone astray", but it sounds rather dated.

Comment: +1.  Though "to stray off course" is still current in the literal sense.